# Snappy timeout while generating PDF with Silex

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, silex, snappy

I have a Silex project where I want to generate a PDF of a view of this project.

I installed locally [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) on OSX, and i'm using [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy).

For example, you're on `localhost:8001/test/702254` and the page appears. If you access `localhost:8001/test/702254/print` then the page will be the PDF of the previous (I want the browser show the PDF to the client, then he can download it).

I have a variable in my routes and if it has the 'print' value I want to display the PDF.

```
$body = null;
$headers = null;

if ($request->get('print') == 'print') {
    $uri = str_replace('/print', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $this->snappy->setOption('cookie', array('MY-COOKIE' => $_COOKIE['MY-COOKIE']));
    //$this->snappy->setTimeout(360);
    $body = $this->snappy->getOutput('http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$uri}");
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="Export.pdf"'
    );
}
else {
    $body = $app['twig']->render('views/index.html.twig', $twigParams);
    $headers = array('Cache-Control' => 'max-age=300, public');
}

return new Response($body, 200, $headers);
```

My problem is when I call the URL with '/print', I have the following error :

```
ProcessTimedOutException in Process.php line 1211:

The process "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --cookie 'MY-COOKIE' '4vkvcjnt2svf0' 'http://localhost:8001/test/702254' '/var/folders/2h/qwnt4dk97dsg1mhv_63ycbrh0000gp/T/knp_snappy574713575a5e51.78801388.pdf'" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.
```

I hope it is not an 'OSX issue' as I read in some topics...

Comment: As far as I know, it'll not work on OSX at all.
It's a [known issue](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/58).
First, try to run it on a linux environment to eliminate the doubt.
If the problem persists then try to remove all `<link/>` and `<script/>` tags that include files (external or internal), it will surely solve the problem. If it is, create a specific template for the print route, then past the specific css directly into using a `<style/>` (and `script` for js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yes it works, because the 'inline' command directly in the shell works. Some topics are speaking about a native php server issue that isn't multi-thread, but apache and nginx are. So I'll try it with one of these before try your solution ;)

Comment: The 'inline' command would always work as it is not ran by php but by your user shell itself. It is not relevant as knp snappy uses php exec() with its own intent. I have no idea weither it might be related to your environment but you should try saving your session and injecting it [as explained here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/69). Hope it works.